# stretchableImageWithLeftCap: --> drawInRect -->very slow?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem with  stretchable images in my tableView.
Until Today I used static backgroundimages with 320px width.

But as I want to support landscape too, I thought I switch to stretchable images instead of using a seperate png file.

The first thing I noticed, was that the scrolling performance was really bad.
I didn't change anything else.

After that I started some time measuring, and removed everything from the drawing routine beside the stretchable image.

The "drawContentView" method needs factor 10 of the time, compared to using a non-stretched image with the same size of as the backroundRect.
With stretching the lags are easy to see. Without it scolls like a charm.

```
static UIImage *greyBackground = nil;

+ (void)initialize
{
  greyBackground = [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_gray.png"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:65.0 topCapHeight:0.0]retain];
}


- (void)drawContentView:(CGRect)r {
  CGRect backgroundRect = contentView.bounds;

  [greyBackground drawInRect:backgroundRect];
}
```

Is the performance of this really that bad, or is something wrong here?
Tested on an iPhone 4, so should be powerful enough normally. :-/

I already thought about caching the correct sized image instead of the stretchable,
and recreate it with the new size after screen rotation.

But I know a lot app that use cell background images and different cell heights (e.g. Twitter a.k.a. Tweetie) and still scrolls amazing fast.

So, should it normally work better, or is stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth something I better avoid?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with custom cell backgrounds, but is this manual drawing needed? Isn't there a backgroundImage-property like in UIView?
Also, caching sounds very good, I would try that if there's no other way than using custom drawing functions.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot elements to be drawn, and the performance after drawing it by myself with cached objects is really better.

Just the stretchableImage is the problem.

The stretchable image itself is already cached as you can see (static pointer and retain).
But if there's no other solution, I will switch to cache the final image instead.

I was just wondering how other apps are doing that.

The whole rest of the cell (3 Strings, 5 other (non-stretchable) images) are drawn in less then the half time compared to this single stretchable image :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to solve the problem but still can't believe that this should be normal behavior of stretchableImageWithLeftCap:...

I sliced my backgroundPicture in 3 parts now.
- leftCap
- middlePart (1px width)
- rightCap

Left and right caps are drawn with drawAtPoint, middlePart ist drawn with drawAsPatternInRect.
Drawing this 3 cached images is more or less as fast as my original, fullsize backgroundImage was.

But I always thought stretchableImageWithLeftCap would do the same: Drawing 2 Caps and and 1px patterns between.
No idea why it's so slow for me.